# WPF Controls disappear in certain culture

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

OK, this is very strange, and I don't even know how to begin debugging this issue. Let’s start with some background:
I don’t know if it's relevant, but maybe I should point out that it’s a WinForms application, slowly being transformed to a WPF application. So I’m using WPF User Control in WinForms Elementhost. I have made a lot of WPF controls, that I’m using all over in our application. Our application is supported in a dozen languages. One being Portuguese. 
When I set the culture for the WinForms application to “pt-PT” some of my controls start to look very strange.

As you can see on the below attached screenshots, the margins are all screwed up, some of the text are missing, and some controls disappear altogether.

[image][image]
[image][image]

This is the XAML for one of the controls that disappear:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ellab.WPF.View.EllabWPFStretchButtonView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:Ellab.WPF.Utilities"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/FadeOutImageStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ToolTipStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClickCommand}"
        utilities:ControlEventBehaviour.MouseEnterCommand="{Binding Path=MouseEnter}"
        utilities:ControlEventBehaviour.MouseLeaveCommand="{Binding Path=MouseLeave}"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}" MinWidth="{Binding Path=Width}" MinHeight="{Binding Path=Height}" Margin="{Binding Path=Margin}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=FadeOutImage}" 
                       Visibility="{Binding FadeOutVisible}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=FadeOutImageVerticalAlignment}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=FadeOutImageHorizontalAlignment}" 
                       Width="{Binding Path=Width}" 
                       Height="{Binding Path=Height}"
                       Style="{StaticResource DefaultFadeOutImageStyle}"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=OverlayImage}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=OverlayImageVerticalAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=OverlayImageHorizontalAlignment}"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=TextBlock}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

And this is how I use it

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ellab.Main.Settings.SettingsWindow.View.SettingsLogoConfigurationView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ContentPresenterStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=HeaderButton}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultContentPresenter}"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ControlButtons}" Width="350">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=LogoImage}" MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="250" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Anyone have any idea what could cause this? Please shoot from the hip, and give me your best guess. I'm really at a lost here, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Christian

Comment: If this behavior appears only for one language I suppose you should start from checking localization. 1. Check how localization is made in your project. 2. Check Portuguese localization files 3. In usercontrols that does not appear - remove inner controls one by one to find controls that could cause errors. 4. If such control exists, remove its properties in xaml one by one to search error. If not - write here that error is not in usercontrol and not in localization files

Comment: @VMaleev, Thanks. I try.